# get object inside every call Retrofit

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

i'm using Retrofit and RxJava to integrate with an API every api response is like that:

```
{"success":true,"message":null,"object":{"bla":"String", "bla1":1}}
```

And the only thing that change is the `object`, i tried to create a "ResponseBase" and every model extends that, and create a "Response", that is what api will aways return

```
public class Response {
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
    public ResponseBase object;
}
```

And to get the object type i want i just cast in a `.map`

```
//VehicleResponseModel extends ResponseBase

VehicleResponseModel vec = (VehicleResponseModel) response.getObject();
```

But this error happens:

> ResponseBase cannot be cast to VehicleResponseModel

i don't have in mind a clearly way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generics for that:

`public class Response<T> {
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
    public T object;
}`

And make your retrofit return `Response<VehicleResponseModel>` so you can retrieve your `VehicleResponseModel` from it

Comment: Appear this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to VehicleResponseModel

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your inheritance model:

This should be your parent class:

```
public class Response {
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
}
```

This could be one of the child classes (representing the included data model):

```
public class SomeResponse extends Response {

    public InnerModel object;

    public static class InnerModel {
        public String bla;
        public int bla1; 
    }
}
```

Then when you receive an instance of your `SomeResponse` you can easily access e.g. `someResponse.object.bla1`.

Comment: Why are you convicing him he is trying to do right thing with inheritance/? Just go for generics

Comment: I'm not trying to convince him to do anything? I'm just pointing out that currently his inheritance is WRONG. I'm presenting one way he can fix it, generics is another good way of doing that. Choosing one or the other really depends on his needs and preferred style.

Comment: using generics this happens: LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to VehicleResponseModel

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to go with generics you should read this : [Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)

Or you can go with the answer Bartek mentioned above.

```
public class ResponseBase {
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
}

public class VehicleResponseModel extends ResponseBase {
    //Your custom vehicle model
}
```

And then make your retrofit interface return VehicleResponseModel.